# how to listen to the deletion of a specific character javascript

Tags: javascript

Im having trouble trying to find a solution to this..

How can I listen for the deletion/backspace of a certain character

So I know I can listen for a backspace event like so..

```
function() {
    const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
    const backspace = 8;
    textarea.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        if(event.keyCode === backspace) {
           // do something
        }
    });
}
```

but what I want to do is if I backspace and the character that was removed was an `@` - then do something

How could I do something like this??

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: try out what mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061763/how-to-know-which-characters-isare-get-deleted-on-backspace-or-delete?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `selectionStart` of the `textarea` to get the caret position, then access that index of the value (minus one) to get the character that's going to be deleted:

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
const backspace = 8;
textarea.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.keyCode === backspace) {
    console.log('backspace');
    const { value } = textarea;
    const charToBeDeleted = value[textarea.selectionStart - 1];
    if (charToBeDeleted === '@') {
      console.log('deleting @...');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Also make sure you use `===` to check for equality - `=` is assignment.

If you want to check for the possibility of the user deleting more than just one character via selection, then you'll have to check `selectionEnd` as well, and `slice` the value appropriately:

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
const backspace = 8;
textarea.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.keyCode === backspace) {
    console.log('backspace');
    const { value, selectionStart, selectionEnd } = textarea;
    const stringToBeDeleted =
      selectionStart === selectionEnd
      ? value[selectionStart - 1]
      : value.slice(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
    
    console.log(stringToBeDeleted);
    
    if (stringToBeDeleted.includes('@')) {
      console.log('deleting @...');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo and thanks this works really well!! I will mark your answer as correct in 8 minutes